# Firebase Java setters and getters with nested pojos

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, getter-setter

which setters/getters for firebase should I add when having a pojo that has some primitive fields and another field that is an object I created?

Something like this

```
class Run :
    long time
    long date
    Distance distance

class Distance :
    double distanceKm
```

`Run` would be the class that I'm adding to the database.

If I add setters and getters for `time`, `date`, `distance` and then `distanceKm` on `Run` like this :

```
public double getDistanceKm(){
    return distance.getDistanceKm();
}

public void setDistanceKm(double x){
    distance.setDistanceKm(x);
}
```

I get a null pointer crash when I start the app because firebase calls those methods without calling `setDistance()` first, so distance is null and it crashes.

If I remove those getters and setters, and make the only way to get to `distanceKm` by doing `getDistance().getDistanceKm()` it works, but it silently outputs dozens of warnings like this :

`W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for distanceKilometres found on class com.example.tobias.run.data.Run (fields/setters are case sensitive!)`

If it helps, this the relevant parts of the run class:

```
public class Run {

private Distance distance;
private long time;
private long date;
private int rating;
private long milePace;
private long kilometrePace;
private String id = null;

public Run(Distance distance, long time, long date, int rating) {
    this.distance = distance;
    this.time = time;
    this.date = date;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.kilometrePace = calculatePace(this.distance.getDistanceKm(), time);
    this.milePace = calculatePace(this.distance.getDistanceMi(), time);
}

@Deprecated
/**
 * This no-arg constructor is required and should only be used by firebase, never by a user,
 * because it will lead to the object being in an invalid state where no fields are initialized.
 */
public Run(){}

private long calculatePace(float distance, long time){
    //Period is inputted time in millis and converts it to hh:mm:ss
    Period period = new Period(time);
    float timeInSeconds = period.getHours() * 3600f + period.getMinutes() * 60f + period.getSeconds();
    float pace = timeInSeconds / distance;
    //Multiply pace by 1000 to convert it to millis from seconds.
    return (long) pace * 1000;
}


public float getDistanceKilometres(){
    return distance.getDistanceKm();
}

public float getDistanceMiles(){
    return distance.getDistanceMi();
}

public long getTime(){
    return time;
}

public long getDate(){
    return date;
}

public int getRating(){
    return rating;
}

public String getId(){ return id; }

public long getMilePace(){
    return milePace;
}

public long getKilometrePace() {
    return kilometrePace;
}

public Distance getDistance(){
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(Distance distance){
    this.distance = distance;
    updatePace();
}

public void setTime(long time){
    this.time = time;
    updatePace();
}

public void setDate(long date){
    this.date = date;
}

public void setRating(int rating){
    this.rating = rating;
}

public void setId(String pushKey){
    id = pushKey;
}

@Deprecated
/**
 * Setter required for Firebase, should not be used by user as pace should never be set manually,
 * only computed off distance and time values, to avoid inconsistencies.
 */
public void setKilometrePace(long kmPace){
    this.kilometrePace = kmPace;
}

@Deprecated
/**
 * Setter required for Firebase, should not be used by user as pace should never be set manually,
 * only computed off distance and time values, to avoid inconsistencies.
 */
public void setMilePace(long milePace){
    this.milePace = milePace;
}
```

}

And this is the relevant parts of the Distance class :

```
public class Distance {

private float distanceKm;
private float distanceMi;

public enum Unit {
    KM("km"), MILE("mi");

    private String value;

    Unit(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}

public Distance(float distance, Unit unit){
    roundNearestTenth(distance);

    if (unit == Unit.MILE){
        distanceMi = distance;
        distanceKm = mileToKm(distance);
    } else  {
        distanceKm = distance;
        distanceMi = kmToMile(distance);
    }
}

@Deprecated
/**
 * This no-arg constructor is required and should only be used by firebase, never by a user,
 * because it will lead to the object being in an invalid state where no fields are initialized.
 */
public Distance(){}

public float getDistanceKm() {
    return distanceKm;
}

public float getDistanceMi() {
    return distanceMi;
}

public void setDistanceKm(float distanceKm) {
    distanceKm = roundNearestTenth(distanceKm);
    this.distanceKm = distanceKm;
    this.distanceMi = kmToMile(distanceKm);
}

public void setDistanceMi(float distanceMi) {
    distanceMi = roundNearestTenth(distanceMi);
    this.distanceMi = distanceMi;
    this.distanceKm = mileToKm(distanceMi);
}
```

}

And my firebase console show the following structure :

```
[pushKey]
    -date
    -id
    -kilometrePace
    -milePace
    -rating
    -time
    -distanceKm
    -distanceMi
    +distance
        -distanceKm
        -distanceMi
```

What seems to be the cause is the fact that `distanceKm` and `distanceMi` fields are duplicated. Should they be only inside `distance` or is this intended behavior? What should I do to remove that warning then?

Thanks (:

Comment: It would be very helpful if you edited your answer to show the entire pojo, and an example of what exactly is in your database that it's being mapped into that pojo.  Right now I can only guess.

Comment: @DougStevenson updated

Answer (score 1):

Your code is depending on the order in which setters are called, which is not good.  Your pojo should allow fields to be set in any order.  As you suggested, having duplication between Run and Distance is probably not a good idea.  As a general rule, pojo object should do litte more than contain structured data, and not so much logic that depends on the state of the fields of the object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the duplication of fields in the firebase console intended?

Comment: The console only shows what you put in the database.  So I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: In the database, why is distanceKm and distanceMi inside of run and also inside of Distance? Shouldn't it be only inside Distance? because Run doesn't have a distanceKm or distanceMi field.

Comment: I don't know.  So far you've only talked about how you're *reading* the data out of it.  You haven't said anything about how you're *writing* it.